# how to break a vector into subvectors in R

Tags: r

I have a vector like:

```
A B C A B A B D D E
```

and I'd like to break it into as many vectors as the number of "A" I have, like:

```
A B C
A B
A B D D E
```

is there a way to accomplish this task?

Comment: If I got you right you want to break the vector every time you find an "A". Is that correct?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `split` and `cumsum`:

```
split(x, cumsum(x == "A"))
```

What you get in return is a `list` of vectors. A `list` seems most useful to me here since it allows vectors of different sizes in each element (unlike a `data.frame` for instance).

Comment: If you're looking to replicate this approach with slightly different functions, you can also use `split(x, cumsum(x %in% "A"))`

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as `split` approach but we can go also for `strsplit`:

```
strsplit(paste0("A", strsplit(paste0(vec, collapse = ""), "A")[[1]][-1]),"")

# [[1]]
# [1] "A" "B" "C"

# [[2]]
# [1] "A" "B"

# [[3]]
# [1] "A" "B" "D" "D" "E"
```